# Efficient way to count ints in line C/C++

Tags: c++

I've been tasked with solving a rather simple problem but I'm stuck on 1 thing

Given the following file structure:

```
4
124 123 145 152
1400
13 23 51 24 1412 5151 52512 12412...
...
```

I am supposed to do various tasks with data but before doing anything with it I have to check whether int in first line corresponds to number of ints in 2nd line (same for 3rd and 4th line)
The problem is the number of elements can reach up to 150 000 and int value is between (1;2 000 000) so using getline can be problematic (afaik) as it will be resource heavy.
Cin will ignore whitespaces and \n so I will never know when line ends
I can't modify the original file and I try to use as least resources as possible.

Comment: 150 000 values of say 5 digits on average, plus spaces, = 900 000 bytes, which is about 1/8000 of memory on a typical PC. What is the problem?

Comment: Is the goal efficiency or correctness?  In general you would expect to have the latter before seeking out the former.  If you've already got the correct program, what are the key elements of efficiency you want to focus on?

Comment: To avoid allocating space for the whole line, you would have to write a (very) small parser.  Read characters one at a time using `cin.get` . Then if it is a digit and either it is the first char on the line, or the previous char was space, then count 1.  Abort if you hit a char that is neither digit nor space, and finish when you read `\n`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The overall goal is efficiency but so far I try to narrow down a working alghoritm. I admit that programming is not my first major and sometimes it does not seems so obvious but isn't getline storing this in RAM memory? I'll try to run some sample data and check how it's handled.

Comment: Yes, `getline` stores the data in RAM, and there's quite enough of it.

Comment: It took a bit time but I can say that @Cheersandhth.-Alf gave me somewhat good answer. Getline is not as dreaded as my colleague had told me. I can send it to stringstream and then easily manipulate it as I want (+ using vectors (which gives me ability to check 1st line against real number of elements + make some quick changes/fixes to data) instead of dynamic pointer arrays but that's not a part of my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom function to take the integer values, Something like this:

```
int getints(){
    int ctr = 0;
    char ch;
    int sign = 1, n=0;
    while(ch!='\n'){
        while(ch==' ' || ch=='\t')
            ch = getchar();
        if(ch=='-'){
            sign = -1;
            ch = getchar();
        }
        while(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
            n = n*10 + ch - '0';
            ch = getchar();
        }
        n *= sign;
        ++ctr;
    }
    return ctr;
}
```

This function will return the number of integers scanned in a line. Just check it with the number of integers that are supposed in a line. It basically skips all whitespace characters and terminates input after newline is found.

Comment: Looks nice! I've stumbled upon simmilar solution. It solves everything when the only thing  i need to do is to count whitespaces/digits/numbers in line. As a resolution i'm going to stick with getline and hope that the ammount of memory is sufficient (and try to think of handling event of not being able to load entire line). I know it's not perfect solution but given deadlines it's the easiest and the fastest to achieve for me.

Answer (score 1):

hm not sure if i understand the question completely but why dont you use getline to store the line that contains 1400 ints as a string. Afterwards using a istringstream make sure you read 1400 ints. Maybe something like this:

```
getline(cin, line);
while(iss >> n && i++ < numOfInts) {}
```

then outside make sure i == numOfInts.
This way you'll never actually be storing 1400 ints, you'll just keep overwriting the previous integer

Comment: OP's objection to this is that it must allocate memory for the entire line, which could use unnecessary resource if the line contains millions of ints

Comment: Also you didn't say what `iss` is, presumably you meant `istringstream iss( std::move(line) );`

Comment: I did mention istringstream above the code;

Comment: Also if you don't want to save that line in the memory, you could overload the cin operator to just read an integer then; so just overload the >> operator to just read an int and  you'll still be using the same while loop rather it would just be something like while(cin >> n && i++ < numOfInts) {}

Comment: It's not possible to overload `istream::operator>>` for builtin types, you'd have to make custom target